# How to properly remove my label when there is no match in entry box tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, label

I am fetching a cell from an excelsheet to display as a label in my TKinter window.  When there is no match it should delete the text.
I find the name and the results are as I want it to

[image]

When I remove the text from my name entry I want the name to dissapear. But then this happens.

[image]

Looks like it's trying to overwrite the text with blank text.

My code :

```
from tkinter import * 
import csv
import time
from openpyxl import load_workbook



class App(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()
        self.output()

def clock(self):
    self.hour = time.strftime("%H")
    self.minute = time.strftime("%M")
    self.second = time.strftime("%S")
    self.klockan.config(text = self.hour + ":" + self.minute + ":" + self.second)
    self.klockan.after(1000, self.clock)


#Leta värden i excel namn.xlsx
def excelinfo(self):
    self.wb = load_workbook("namn.xlsx",read_only=True)
    self.ws = self.wb.active
    self.excelnamn = self.excelnamn = Label(text="",font=('Arial', 10)).grid(row=1,column=2)
    if len(self.namn.get()) > 2:
        for i in self.ws.rows:
            if i[0].value == self.namn.get():
                self.excelnamn = Label(text=i[1].value,font=('Arial', 10)).grid(row=1,column=2)
                # self.excelnamn = self.excelnamn(text=i[1])
                # self.excelföretag = i[2].value
        else:
            pass
    self.namn.after(1000, self.excelinfo)
      


def output(self):
    #Tid
    self.klockan = Label(root, text='', font=('Arial',25))
    self.klockan.grid(row=0, column=2)
    self.clock()


    #Etiketter
    Label(text='Namn:').grid(row=1,column=0)
    self.namn = Entry(root, width=10)
    self.namn.grid(row=1,column=1)
    self.namn.insert(END,"ES")
    self.excelinfo()
    


 
def writeToFile(self):
    self.checknum()
    with open('Test.csv', 'a') as f:
        w=csv.writer(f, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
        w.writerow([

            self.namn.get()

            ])
    self.clear()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root=Tk()
    root.title('Auto Logger')
    root.geometry('800x600')
    app=App(master=root)
    app.mainloop()
    root.mainloop()
```

i've tried altering the code using .destroy() and .grid_forget() but destoy gives me no attribute to destroy error. and grid.forget() the name no longer appears in the box.

```
    #Leta värden i excel namn.xlsx
def excelinfo(self):
    self.wb = load_workbook("namn.xlsx",read_only=True)
    self.ws = self.wb.active
    self.excelnamn = self.excelnamn = Label(text="",font=('Arial', 10))
    self.excelnamn.grid(row=1,column=2)
    if len(self.namn.get()) > 2:
        for i in self.ws.rows:
            if i[0].value == self.namn.get():
                self.excelnamn = Label(text=i[1].value,font=('Arial', 10))
                self.excelnamn.grid(row=1,column=2)
                # self.excelnamn = self.excelnamn(text=i[1])
                # self.excelföretag = i[2].value
        else:
            self.excelnamn.grid_forget()
    self.namn.after(1000, self.excelinfo)


self.excelnamn.destroy()
```

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'destroy'

Comment: Full error code please

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tkinter: AttributeError: NoneType object has no attribute <attribute name>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101750/tkinter-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-attribute-name)

Comment: No, sorry.  My original code gives no errors. If you look at the screenshots the only thing I see happening is that abit of the text dissapears when the statement is false.

Comment: Make a single label and then update the label with `config()` method

Comment: Did not work either. I think I might have done something wrong in the code somwere.